# how to convert 'Set' from Vb to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

How to convert the following VB code to C# code?

```
Set atDIOAOIPIsReady = _
atDIOGObjRepos.InsertOutputObjectIfNew(sIPIsReadyID, atDIOAOIPIsReady)
```

My idea is :

```
atDIOAOIPIsReady -= atDIOGObjRepos.InsertOutputObjectIfNew(ref sIPIsReadyID,atDIOAOIPIsReady);
```

But it showed me the error as following:

1. The best overload method match for

   ```
   ActivVTools._AVTDIOFObjectRepository.InsetOutputObjectIfNew(ref string, ref ActivVTools._IAVTDIOObject)
   ```

   has some invalid arguments.
2. Argument '1' must be passed with the 'ref' keyword
3. Argument '2' cannot convert from `ActivVTools.AVTDIOActionObjectClass` to `ref ActivVTools._IAVTDIOObject`

Comment: I hope the `-=` in your C# line is a typo in the post. You just need an `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](http://download.mvtec.com/activdigitalio.pdf)(pdf) you need to first create an AVTDIOActionObjectClass object. In the sample they showed, they set the Description property which will not be necessary.

The SET keyword is VB6 and has been used to assign references to a variable. Nowadays with VB.NET this isn`t used/needed anymore.

The C# code would be (see the `ref`keyword for the second parameter):

```
AVTDIOActionObjectClass atDIOAOIPIsReady=new AVTDIOActionObjectClass ();
atDIOAOIPIsReady= atDIOGObjRepos.InsertOutputObjectIfNew(ref sIPIsReadyID, 
                  ref atDIOAOIPIsReady);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
atDIOAOIPIsReady = atDIOGObjRepos.InsertOutputObjectIfNew(ref sIPIsReadyID, atDIOAOIPIsReady);
```